# query with variables c#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have int ID in my form load function, and while loading i want datagridview to fill with data where someColumn like '%?@ID%', but when i write it like this it doesn't work. Explain to me how it need to be done.

Here is load code:

```
    private void PopisnaLista_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dataSet1.ROBA' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.rOBATableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.ROBA);
        try
        {
            this.rOBATableAdapter.FillBy(this.dataSet1.ROBA);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Here is query for FillBy

```
SELECT        ROBAID, KATBR, KATBRPRO, NAZIV, VRSTA, AKTIVNA, GRUPAID, PODGRUPA, PROID, JM, TARIFAID, NABAVNACENA, PRODAJNACENA, DEVNABCENA, FABRCENA, STANJE, NARUCENO, REZERVISANO, 
                         STANJEPOOTP, TAKSA, MARZA, UVOZ, TARBROJ, AKCIZA, NAZIVZACARINU, NAZIVNAENG, GARANTID, ALTJM, ALTKOL, ALTNEDELJIVA, TRPAK, TRKOL, JMSD, KOMENTAR, XOD, XDO, YOD, YDO, ZOD, ZDO, 
                         IMAROKTRAJANJA, NACENOVNIKU, ZAPID, NORMA, KALO, TEZINA, PIN, KRITZAL, OPTZAL, KATEGORIJA, IMASBROJ, STANJEPOSER, ZAPREMINA, SLIKA, PPID, TRDECPAK, PRODCENABP, JMR, 
                         STANJEPOREKLAM, STANJEPOREVERSU, ADR, STANJE_MOJE_EKSP, VPCID, PROCPC, DATUM_ISPORUKE, REZERVISANO_MOJE_EKSP, STANJEPOOTP_MOJE_EKSP, STANJEPOSER_MOJE_EKSP, 
                         NAZIVZASTAMPU, ALTPIN, TRPIN, DRZAVAID, LINKED_ROBAID, OBLIK, REKLAM_PROC, JM_POVRSINA, JM_ZAPREMINA, X3, Y3, Z3, NAS_BARKOD
FROM            ROBA
WHERE        (KATBRPRO LIKE '%?@ID')
```

Comment: the @ID is a string there. put it as '%?'+@ID+'''

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `Like` for an ID? If you are using the ID is for identifing one row and not all the rows that contains a `1` in the ID

Comment: Dynamic SQL Error - expression evaluation not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.

First write `(KATBRPRO LIKE @ID)`, then FillBy will take 2 arguments(dataSet, variable in query(@ID)) but because my id is number and i need `%?` in front of it i just add that in argument and join to ID so code looks like this:

```
        try
        {
            this.rOBATableAdapter.FillBy(this.dataSet1.ROBA, "%?" + ID.ToString());
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

And Query

```
SELECT        ROBAID, KATBR, KATBRPRO, NAZIV, VRSTA, AKTIVNA, GRUPAID, PODGRUPA, PROID, JM, TARIFAID, NABAVNACENA, PRODAJNACENA, DEVNABCENA, FABRCENA, STANJE, NARUCENO, REZERVISANO, 
                         STANJEPOOTP, TAKSA, MARZA, UVOZ, TARBROJ, AKCIZA, NAZIVZACARINU, NAZIVNAENG, GARANTID, ALTJM, ALTKOL, ALTNEDELJIVA, TRPAK, TRKOL, JMSD, KOMENTAR, XOD, XDO, YOD, YDO, ZOD, ZDO, 
                         IMAROKTRAJANJA, NACENOVNIKU, ZAPID, NORMA, KALO, TEZINA, PIN, KRITZAL, OPTZAL, KATEGORIJA, IMASBROJ, STANJEPOSER, ZAPREMINA, SLIKA, PPID, TRDECPAK, PRODCENABP, JMR, 
                         STANJEPOREKLAM, STANJEPOREVERSU, ADR, STANJE_MOJE_EKSP, VPCID, PROCPC, DATUM_ISPORUKE, REZERVISANO_MOJE_EKSP, STANJEPOOTP_MOJE_EKSP, STANJEPOSER_MOJE_EKSP, 
                         NAZIVZASTAMPU, ALTPIN, TRPIN, DRZAVAID, LINKED_ROBAID, OBLIK, REKLAM_PROC, JM_POVRSINA, JM_ZAPREMINA, X3, Y3, Z3, NAS_BARKOD
FROM            ROBA
WHERE        (KATBRPRO LIKE  @ID)
```